# Error when using service: "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract"

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I'm trying to switch my WCF service from TCP bindings to HTTP bindings by modifying `app.config`, but when I try consuming the WCF service from a test console application, I get this error:

> `Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IUsers' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.`

Here's the newer app.config using HTTP bindings that gives me the error above:

```
<services>
  <service name="Test.UserServ" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Users" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" 
        contract="Test.IUsers" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Here's the older working app.config that still uses TCP bindings:

```
<services>
  <service name="Test.UserServ" behaviorConfiguration="TCPBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8731/Users"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPConfiguration" 
        contract="Test.IUsers"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TCPConfiguration">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TCPBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration or is this due to some limitation imposed by the HTTP bindings I've switched to?

Comment: Where's the contract `ServiceReference1.IFile` mentioned in the error message?? I don't see any trace of that service contract anywhere in your configs (neither old nor new). Is your test app's config referencing a wrong URL, maybe??

Comment: @marc_s : That was just a typo. I have a bunch of other services as well, all with the exact same configuration. The actual error message in my example refers to `ServiceReference1.IUser`. Thanks for pointing this out. As for the URL, I'm certain that the test app is referencing the correct one.

Comment: What's the `WsHttpMtomBinding` for?

Comment: I think your problem is this: your `netTcpBinding` service is a **SOAP** service - but your new http config uses all `webHttpBinding` which is a **REST** service..... you're not just changing the binding, but you're changing the whole service core setup..... that won't just work ..... you'll need to redo your client when you change from SOAP to REST...

Comment: Can you show us the **client-side** config, too??

Comment: @Darin : That's just a binding being used by a SOAP service that I forgot to edit out before posting the code here.

Comment: @marc_s : I haven't paid any attention at all to the client-side config since I didn't need to edit it when I was using TCP bindings with SOAP services. Perhaps that is the issue here? Also, does everything look OK on the server-side app.config?

Comment: Yes, as long as you remember you're now dealing with a **REST** service (`webHttpBinding`) - things look OK otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your client config file specifies two endpoints. Both the old TCP endpoint and your new HTTP endpoint. Either delete the old TCP endpoint in your client config file or use the constructor when declaring the client in your code (the constructor takes the name of an endpoint as a string, smth like `new YourClient("NameOfWsHttpBinding");`).